# How to change password securely in Meteor?

Tags: meteor

If use `Accounts.changePassword(oldPassword, newPassword, [callback])`, user can change his password to anything he wants in browser console because this function is executed in client side. (And how can I disable it??)

If use `Accounts.setPassword(userId, newPassword, [options])`, I have to send the old-password and new-password to server, how can I avoid send it in plain text, to secure the password?

Comment: Can you state your goals a little more clearly? Are you trying to enforce, for example, a minimum password length?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Old and new passwords are NOT sent plain text over the wire, it states so in the manual. The passwords are encoded client-side and sent over the wire encrypted.

changePassword() however comes with the accounts-password package and doesn't provide a callback on the server, nor does it allow a configuration setting for preventing password changes. If you don't want that to be available on the client, don't install accounts-password and roll your own package. I wonder however why you would want to do that.